# Is there a proverb in English to convey the meaning "Attempting to catch a flying bird by accidentally releasing the one in hand."?

Tags: proverbs

> Attempting to catch a flying bird by accidentally releasing the one in
> hand.

For example, pursuing other attractive objects for getting more benefit but accidentally losing the benefits from the existing owned objects.

Is there such a proverb in English with the above meaning?

Comment: This question virtually defines *A bird in hand*. Someone write it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A bird in hand is worth two in the bush*.

> Used to say that it is better to hold onto something one has than to risk losing it by trying to get something better. [[Merriam Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20bird%20in%20the%20hand%20is%20worth%20two%20in%20the%20bush)

*Grasp all, lose all* also conveys the idea.

> One who wants everything may lose it all. [[Wikitionary]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grasp_all,_lose_all)